# Google map, jquery and XML

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps

In this link you can get a code: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/advanced-example.html Here is how to change infowindow with jquery window (very nice) but i need to implement this code in my code: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html

How to do that? (sorry for english)

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html    you don't need to output xml using PHP like it that example, it's still a tutorial you can look at if you just have a static xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a dialog instead of an InfoWindow, comment out this line in your code:

`bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);`

and replace it with this:

`$('<div>').html(html).dialog();`

---

To implement `MarkerClusterer`, update the code:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
mc.addMarker(marker);
```

---

Complete `load()` function:

```
function load() {
  var dialog = $('<div>').dialog({autoOpen:false});
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      mc.addMarker(marker);
      //bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       dialog.html(html).dialog('open');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me... but i dont see the markers. Here is the code: http://kuponik.adriamart.com/davidimo.html Where I wrong? Where is error?

Comment: You need to link to the source code for `MarkerClusterer` in your `head`. Google where to download it.

Comment: Cool, but window is open automaticly... you can see what is the problem: http://kuponik.adriamart.com/davidimo.html Sorry for i'm boring you but jquery window is open automaticly and dont show when i click on marker. :(

Comment: and when i click on one marker automaticly close other window and show other... how to do that?

Comment: I have updated the code to include an event listener. Try looking at the code samples you have and figuring out how it works instead of just copying and pasting. Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Comment: When i click on marker always show the same data... but thanks for all again i will find the way to solve the my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) the XML file using AJAX. Then you can parse the file using JQuery selectors and create an array of `Markers` using that data. Pass the markers to a `MarkerClusterer` and the rest of the code will be standard map initialization. Let me know if need more details than that but I cannot help more without knowing the structure of the XML.

Comment: I will create a xml with this file: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_genxml.php and looks like this:

Comment: <markers>
<marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/>

Comment: also i parse the xml with: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.htmlbut i need to implement other code becouse i want to show jquery winow insted classic infoWindow on google map.

Comment: also how to add jquery window instead infowindow on this code: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html

Comment: That is not your original question. Please rewrite your question so that others know what you need.

Comment: In this link you can get a code: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/advanced-example.html Here is how to change infowindow with jquery window (very nice) but i need to implement this code in my code: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html

How to do that? (sorry for english)

Comment: What I need is an php who load my xml file and change infowindow with jquery window.